# facebook messenger Webview and Messenger Extensions

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image: This is facebook messenger additional messenger extension]

I am using JSON which is node.js for Facebook Messenger. What should I do if I want to do exactly the same as image above or this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/introduction/conversation-components

Comment: what source code can be found or what should i do? in JSON format

Answer (score 0):

The menu that has been opened there is a Webview.
It is a page that have been designed with these buttons. The buttons could be used to send requests to your server.
To define the height as on the screen, you have to pass a parameter to the button that will open the webhook, which is "compact".

```
{
  "type":"web_url",
  "url":"<URL_TO_OPEN>",
  "title":"<BUTTON_TEXT>",
  "webview_height_ratio": "compact",
  "messenger_extensions": "<true|false>",  
  "fallback_url": "<URL_TO_FALLBACK_TO>"
}
```

You can find more information here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/url